# What's a good source to view the history of gameplay changes made to Starcraft 2 so far?

Tags: starcraft-2

Wondering if anyone can link me to a good source page or archive of the change logs from the start of the Starcraft 2 Beta up to currently for changes that have been made to balance the game. For example, 'increased zerglings speed by...', etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I find the [Starcraft Wiki](http://starcraft.wikia.com) a good resource for this

- [Starcraft](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Patch)
- [Starcraft 2 Beta](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/StarCraft_II_beta_patch)
- [Starcraft 2](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/StarCraft_II_version_history)

Here is an example (taken from beta patch 15)

Balance Changes

TERRAN

- Hellion

  - Weapon upgrade bonus decreased from 1 (+1 Light) to 1.
- Reaper

  - Nitro Packs research cost decreased from 100/100 to 50/50.
- Siege Tank

  - Siege Mode damage decreased from 60 to 50.
- Thor

  - Anti-air weapon upgrade bonus decreased from 1 (+1 Light) to 1.

ZERG

- Brood Lord

  - Weapon upgrade bonus decreased from 3 to 2.